# Disable Mac Mail main window from popping up after deleting an email

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, email, catalina

When I'm working or in the middle of something, I may get an email notification. I click on the notification banner on the top right hand corner of my screen to open the email.

The email popups up like this: [image]

As you can see, the program in the background is not the Mail app.

After I click the trash/delete button from that email popup to delete the email, the Mac Mail main window popups up like this: [image]

It's so annoying. There is anyway to disable it so after I delete the app, the main Mail window does not open?

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: What is the macOS version your Mac is running on?

Comment: @Alper Sorry I added the version in the question